# Webpack 4 file-loader works on font files, but not image files

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-file-loader

I am trying to get Webpack 4 to output a .png file into /dist/assets, and have that be used by my index.html file via file-loader.

The .png file *does* output into dist/assets, but it does not get loaded in by the browser. Funny thing, I treat my .png files the same as my font files in my webpack.config.js, and the font files are loaded in by the browser.

Below is my file directory when building

[image: File structure]

Below is code from webpack.config.js that I believe to be pertinent to this issue.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
   module: {
     rules: [
     ...
       {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            outputPath: './assets'
       }
     },
   ...
```

The whole webpack.config.js is below, or can be found (along with the other files) at the [repository](https://github.com/EanKeen/periodic-table/blob/6fdfc1da4a6782ee8d45a09b93222fbdcfb1e7d9/webpack.config.js) in which this code is hosted at.

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      /*publicPath: 'dist'*/
  },
   module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['env']
            }
          }
        },
        {
         test: /\.vue$/,
         //exclude: /node_modules/,
         loader: 'vue-loader',
       },
       {
         test: /\.(sa|sc)ss$/,
         exclude: /node_modules/,
         use: [
           MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
           'css-loader',
           'sass-loader' // Loads a sass / scss file and compiles it to CSS
         ]
       },
       {
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [
           MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
           'css-loader'
         ]
       },
        {
           test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
           loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
             name: '[name].[ext]',
             outputPath: './assets'
           }
        },
        {
          test: /\.svg$/,
          use: [
            'vue-svg-icon-loader'
          ],
        }
      ]
   },
   resolve: {
      alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
      },
      extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
    },
    plugins: [
      new VueLoaderPlugin(),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'bundle.css',
        chunckFilename: '[id].css',
      })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it out, and it works fine with just a minor detail.

I think the real magic here is how wepback-dev-server finds your index.html, and if anything I think that **should** break. Anyway:

Your build (`npm run prod` --> `webpack --mode production`) creates all the right files, but there are no changes to index.html, and there is no index.html generated in your dist-folder.  Usually you copy index or generate from a template for cache-busting (copy-webpack-plugin / html-webpack-plugin) but for now I just copied index.html to the dist folder manually.

Of course now the index pointed at the the wrong assets so I updated:

```
from:   href="./dist/bundle.css"   and   src="./dist/bundle.js"
  to:   href="./bundle.css"        and   src="./bundle.js"
```

and it worked immediately (with placeholder.png and everything). The dist-folder is what you want to serve, so make sure your index-file works from there and not from your project-root.

I used [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to test from the dist folder.

Comment: Okay, that does make sense that my `index.html` file should be included in my /dist. I'll make those changes, use copy-webpack-plugin, and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I used copy-webpack-plugin, to put my index.html in the dist folder. It works great now. Thanks for the help!